# How can I close a javascript metro style app?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Is there a code to exit from the metro style application? In C#,  C++, or VB, there are examples like `CoreApplication.Exit()` but I couldn't find something like that for Javascript.

Comment: javascript has a `window.close()`, if that could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general recommendation is that apps do *not* provide their own close affordances. In your example, closing automatically in response to a loss of network connectivity will appear as if the app crashes under such conditions. As such, it may not actually pass Windows Store certification on that point along (see [requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx), section 3.2 about apps that end unexpectedly). Furthermore, section 3.6 prohibits apps closing themselves as already noted, so you'll fail on that as well.

Calling window.close will generate a crash report that appears within the Windows Store dashboard, and will be logged as an app crash, in fact (this may end up counting against the app in the Store--not sure about that, but I wouldn't risk it). In this case, it's better to use MSApp.terminateApp because the crash report will be much more comprehensive (and you can include your own info). Still, MSApp.terminateApp should only be used for truly unrecoverable conditions.

If you have a condition under which the app can't continue to run effectively, but isn't a crash, per se, like the loss of network connectivity, it's better to inform the user of that condition and let them decide whether to close the app (through Alt +F4 or the top-down swipe close gesture) in response. You should also detect when network connectivity has been restored and continue, of source. This way the app hasn't lost its state and can continue where it left off, thereby providing a contiguous user experience.

Comment: Thank you, your answer and sources you gave helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There is really no explicit "closing" in the [Application Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx) of a Metro style app.

> Generally, users don't need to close apps, they can let Windows manage
>   them. However, users can choose to close an app using the close
>   gesture or by pressing Alt+F4. You can't include any UI in your app to
>   enable the user to close your app, or it won't pass the Store
>   certification process.

You should handle Suspending and Resuming correctly and allow the user to control explicit closing of your application (there is a gesture to close a Metro style app in Windows 8, there is no need to provide a visual affordance like a button).

Comment: In the case that internet connection is lost, I want to close my program. I used window.close(); and it worked.

Comment: window.close will not be used, and I believe will get you rejected from the store.

Comment: Thanks for answers, I think I'll rewrite my application after learning those things :)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `MSApp.terminateApp` function.
Details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/apps/hh770781.aspx